# Prestashop categories do not show name and url in back office

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.6

I have main Categories, Sub Categories and default categories for each product. I entered data via sql in to ps_category_lang table.

All the data seems fine when i look at the sql table. But when i log in to back office.
The data appears to be missing in default categories. Main and sub categories are correct.

[image: default category in the sql table with name and url]
As you can see the default category 1000104001017 has name and link_rewrite.

In the back office you can see the same data with name and ID.
[image: back office view default categories]

But when i edit the default category it is empty. No name and no url.
[image: Missing data in the default categories]

has this happened to anyone? I cannot find any answer even on Prestashop forums. I have made sure that the categories are active. If it helps than I am getting this error

Property PrestaShopLogger->object_id is not valid

But when i google this error there is not much information about it. I do not know in which file this error might be in too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category id size is too long which was causing the conflict.
I have changed the length of category ids and now it works fine.